# compute does not forward packets coming from bridge

Tags: linux, routing, openstack

linux box 10.1.0.4 (eth0) <-> 10.1.0.5 (eth0) Compute1 10.1.1.5 (br-ex) <-> 10.1.1.201 VM

Ping works from 10.1.0.4 to 10.1.1.201 without problems, however ping from 10.1.1.201 to 10.1.0.4 does not work. Routes in both directions are both OK, ip forwarding is enabled.

tcpdump in compute1 in br-ex shows the icmp request, also the request is captured in eth0 10.1.0.5 in Compute1 eth0. However tcpdump in linux box 10.1.0.4 (eth0) shows nothing.

THe strange thing is : How is it possible ping reply when I ping from 10.1.0.4 to 10.1.1.201 to work, but ping from 10.1.1.201 to 10.1.0.4 not working ? Iptables I think and NAT, MASQUARADE etc. makes no sense , as I just want the packet to be just forwarded from 10.1.0.5 to 10.1.0.4. But why is does not work ?

Also I have set the rp_filter to 0, although this also I think makes no sense, as rp_filter is for multihomed interfaces and the possibility of parallel paths which is not the case.

SO any help please ??

Comment: My first guess would be security-group rules, did you check those?

Comment: There are no security groups assigned